# Aligning bones' axes to the global axes

Tags: transforms, armature, bones

I am using the quaternion rotation mode to rotate bones into poses for an animation. For some of my bones, when I increase the X value of the quaternion the bone rotates around the y axis instead. For other bones this does not happen.

I have set all my bone rolls to 0, in case that makes a difference. How can I make all of my bones rotate around the same axis when I modify the same value of their quaternion?

update:

I have discovered that in pose mode bones use the vector from their head to their tail as the y axis and the roll affects the orientation of the x and z axes. Still looking for a way to change these to the global axes.

Comment: if you're not set on Quaternion, I can only recommend using euler, it's much more intuitive and easier to correct in the graph editor

Answer (score 7):

You can recalculate roll, (Armature -> Bone Roll -> Recalculate Roll), or `Shift+N`

This can align bone roll to local or global space.

Comment: Shift+N in Blender 2.8

Answer (score 0):

I've found a method which solves my problem, incase anyone else has the same: I seperate each of the bones and place the tail at the same x and z point with a y value greater than the head, then lock the position of the bones and set the roll to 0. This effectively sets the local axes to the same as the global.